# Active Directory w/ no DC at small remote offices

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I am new to Active Directory and I need to implement AD for an organization that has two larger locations and 5 smaller locations, all connected via an MPLS network.  Here is a simplified diagram of the network:

[image: Diagram]

The main reason for implementing AD here is central authentication & user maintenance (and possible group policies).  No roaming profiles, no Exchange, no file shares or other resource sharing.

The remote locations (C-G) have no servers and given the small number of workstations in these sites and their limited use of AD, I really do not want to install DCs with related infrastructure, cost & administrative overhead in those locations.

I plan to only use one domain, but have not yet decided on OUs, etc. (but overall I am trying to keep things simple).

Questions:

1. Are T1s sufficient for this use of AD (the 5 stations at each location will typically only login 1-2 times / day)?  Or is it likely to be very slow to login & bog down the T1s?
2. Can I use only one site (despite the current 3Mbps link @ site B [to become a 10 Mbps in ~2 months])?  If not, how about putting both DCs @ Site A?
3. Other design recommendations for this scenario (remember, I am an AD noob)?

Comment: All domain controllers in one site would be a single point of failure. If all computers use DC1 and DC2 for primary and secondary DNS, it will probably work fine.

Comment: Just another thing to consider, if any of the sites have the possibility of being comprised, you should consider using a read only domain controller, or RODC instead of fully featured DC. DNS should also be a consideration, especially if you are going to do AD integrated DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AD authentication requires very little bandwidth, especially if you aren't going to be sharing files over the network.  At my company, we have 20-some retail stores with POS stations running Windows 7, and they connect to our main office with DSL lines, most of which are 3 Mb/s down and 768 Kb/s up.  They have absolutely no issues with domain authentication, and we even push Windows updates via WSUS over those lines.  I don't anticipate you would have any problems at all with having a DC at only one location.

Comment: That sounds good.  Are you saying that you only have one DC for the whole network and have never had an issue?  It sounds a bit risky...

Comment: No, we have 2 DC's, but they are both located at the main office.  Therefore, that fact is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Actually, that was one of the questions (#2);  I might also decide to place both DCs in the same location.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Sorry, I had missed that part.  DC's in multiple locations is a good idea if it's feasible.  That way, you're protected against a catastrophe at one location, such as fire, tornado, etc.  The bandwidth needed to keep them synchronized is very minimal.

Comment: I know I'm jumping in late but based on your diagram I'd recommend putting a DC in each of your larger sites if at all possible. 2 reasons for this are reliability and DNS resolution speed.  on the reliability front you don't want your whole company down due to a power or network outage at a single site, spreading the DC's fixes this.  as for DNS while AD auth traffic is lightweight and it doesn't really matter if it takes 1 second or 3 that time delay definitely *does* matter for DNS lookups when browsing the web, and placing a DC at siteB will greatly improve their lookup speed.

Comment: @Mike-Garuccio Good point!  But since the workstations only use AD for authentication, is there a simple way to have them not use the DC's DNS?  I guess I could place the AD server's IP in the host file and leave the DNS setting pointing to their current (external) DNS server?  Note: I realize that this might have to be a separate question...

Comment: There's no requirement to use the DC's as DNS servers but AD integrated DNS has a lot of advantages. Check out [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731204(v=ws.10).aspx) for more info.